# decoding and printing out json data using php

Tags: php, json, ajax

hello I am working on a script that posts a set of json object data to a php file

the json data is stored in a variable myJSON as `{"Peter":"35","Ben":"37","Joe":"43"}`

and is passed below to Ajax post request

```
var data = {
  test: myJSON
};
var options = {
  url: "###############.php",
  dataType: "text",
  type: "POST",
  data: { test: JSON.stringify( data ) },
  success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
     alert(data);
  },
  error: function( xhr, status, error ) {
      alert(status);
      //...
  }
};
$.ajax( options );
```

Next thing in my php script I receive the posted data and I do a var_dump

```
 $someJSON = $_POST['test'];
  echo $array = json_decode($someJSON, true );
    var_dump($array);
```

which results in the below screenshot

[image: var_dump image]

but when I try to print this same data with a for each loop e.g trying to get the details of "Peter"

```
 foreach($array as $item) { 
    echo $item['Peter']; 
}
```

I get this error below

[image: error]

how do I correct this, been stuck on this, please help

Comment: why you're doing JSON.stringify on a string that is already json?

Comment: You need to `json_decode` the data, e.g. `$item = json_decode($item); echo $item['Peter'];`

Comment: Or better yet, as @YourCommonSense says, don't use `JSON.stringify` in your JS code...